# Ethernet Splitter for PC and Printer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, ethernet, splitter

I am looking to connect my printer to an Ethernet cable. I only have one Ethernet port and was thinking on buying a Ethernet splitter to connect my pc and printer at the same time. I have been doing research on splitters an came across that if you have two Ethernet wires connected to the splitter, only one Ethernet cable will work at a time. Will they both work simultaneously if I have a PC and printer connected?

I know they won’t work if you try to simultaneously use two PCs at the same time but I am not sure about having a printer and PC connected simultaneously. I will be connected to my printer wirelessly, so I will not connect my PC through the USB cable.

Comment: Get an Ethernet hub or ethernet switch. They support 4 ports or more and work simultaneously. This is really the solution you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is no such thing as an Ethernet splitter. There is a way for two Ethernet or Fast Ethernet (but not gigabit) connections to ride over a single cable. But since you only have a single Ethernet port with a single connection, that won't help you. Get a switch. Five port gigabit switches cost around $20.

Comment: since networking hardware is cheaper than before, handy andy solutions are out to date.